multiplication of exponential of non-commutative generator
Edit(2024.10.24): sorry for post a bad. and i dont know if allowed to post again. Edited again. Also thanks to previous answer by @Roland F
Background: DOI:10.1063/1.1664490
$H,P_i,K_i,J_i$ is generator.
When multiplying two group elements $(e^{bH}e^{a\cdot P}e^{v\cdot K}e^{in\cdot J})(e^{b'H}e^{a'\cdot P}e^{v'\cdot K}e^{in'\cdot J})$, i hope it to fit into another group element
By using BCH formula:
$e^{A}Be^{-A}=B+[A,B]+\frac{1}{2}[A,[A,B]]+\ldots+\frac{1}{n!}\underbrace{[A,\ldots[A,B]..]}_{\textrm{n comm}}+\ldots$ 
and a formula on Wu-Ki Tong's book:
$RT(b)R^{-1}=T(Rb)$ 
(where $R$ means the rotation element $e^{in\cdot J}$)
Consider the Poincare group it becomes: $e^{AH}e^{B\cdot P}e^{v\cdot K}e^{Rv'\cdot K}e^{in'\cdot J}$ 
As for the commutation rule, i suppose when calculating $e^{v\cdot K}e^{Rv'\cdot K}$ it wont create something like $e^{H}$ or $e^{P}$. (Egh, or it will?)
If $e^{v\cdot K}e^{v'\cdot k}e^{in'\cdot J}$ cannot be trans into the form of $e^{A\cdot K}e^{B\cdot J}$, is there something wrong to the closeness?
Shortly: can $e^{v\cdot K}e^{v'\cdot k}e^{in'\cdot J}$ be turned into the form of $e^{A\cdot K}e^{B\cdot J}$ under the commutation rule $[K_i,K_j]=-\epsilon_{ijk}J_j$, $[J_i,K_j]=\epsilon_{ijk} K_j$ and $[J_i,J_j]=\epsilon_{ijk} J_j$
$(i,j=1,2,3)$?
